# Renting a bike from Beijing Airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, rental, bicycles, pek

Is it possible to rent a bicycle directly from Beijing Capital International Airport? I'm looking for something to do during a day-long layover.

Comment: I've never seen an airport with bicycle rental.  Most are a pain to get to on a bicycle at all.

Comment: Some hostel and hotel next to the airport provide bicycle rental but i don't sure non-residents can use the services

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can rent bicycles around the airport hotels. This depends on whether you are a foreigner or Chinese national.

Most hotels around the airport offer bicycle rentals to Chinese citizens as they only accept an ID card.
Other places close to the airport also offer bicycle rentals though some are a bit far, just a few stops from the airport by subway.

The following numbers **4000887806** and **4001577157** operate *Monday to Friday 9:30 to 11:30, 13:30 to 4:00.*

**Fee:** *1 hour free, after one yuan per hour, maximum charge 10 yuan per day. If you keep the bicycle for more than three days, there is a deduction of 20yuan per day. You might need a bit of Mandarin language they will help you locate the closest rental to where you will be.*

Sorry I forgot to mention earlier, there is a deposit of around 200 or more depending on the bicycle you hire. That is where the 20 yuan charge comes from when you do not return the bike in 3 days. They will give you all their terms.

Comment: Yes its quite generous but they do have a lot of bikes where its mostly students hiring for even months.